# File-field Button is not enabling in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

The file-field type in  Extjs is not working properly. Initially i will be disabling this file field in my code and when i enable this field the browse button(button to select the files) doesn't enable but the buttons function working fine.
Does this problem has any solution. please help me with this.

```
Ext.widget('panel', {
title: 'Test panel', 
width: 400, 
height: 200,
renderTo: 'codeoutput',
layout: 'vbox',
items: [

{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        fieldLabel: 'PAN Number *',
        margin: "20 0 0 0",
        name: 'rb',
        id: 'radioPan',
        inputValue: '1',
        checked: true,
        listeners: {
            change: function (cb, nv, ov) {
                if (nv) {
                    Ext.getCmp('AttachData').disable();
                    Ext.getCmp('PanData').enable();
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'splitter'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        margin: "20 0 0 0",
        id: 'PanData',
        allowBlank: false,
        disabled: false
    }]
},


{
    xtype: 'container',
    html: '[ OR ]',
    margin: "10 0 0 175"
},


{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        fieldLabel: 'Owner\'s Declaration *',
        margin: "10 0 0 0",
        name: 'rb',
        id: 'radioAttach',
        inputValue: '2',
        checked: false,
        listeners: {
            change: function (cb, nv, ov) {
                if (nv) {
                    Ext.getCmp('PanData').disable();
                    Ext.getCmp('AttachData').enable();
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'splitter'
    }, {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        id: 'AttachData',
        name: 'file_path',
        margin: "15 0 0 0",
        buttonText: 'Browse',
        disabled: true
    }]
}] 
});
```

I have selected the file-field but the browse button is disabled
[image]

Comment: which version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be [a bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242022) in ExtJs 4.1.

This is resolved in version ExtJS 4.1.3

We can have a workaround by removing these `'x-disabled x-btn-disabled x-item-disabled x-btn-default-small-disabled'` css classes while enabling the field and again adding these classes while disabling it.
So added following line while disabling the field:

```
Ext.select(".x-btn",Ext.getCmp('AttachData')).addCls('x-disabled x-btn-disabled x-item-disabled x-btn-default-small-disabled');
```

& added following line while enabling the field:

```
Ext.select(".x-btn",Ext.getCmp('AttachData')).removeCls('x-disabled x-btn-disabled x-item-disabled x-btn-default-small-disabled');
```

Full Code:

```
 Ext.widget('panel', {
    title: 'Test panel', 
    width: 400, 
    height: 200,
    renderTo: 'codeoutput',
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [

    {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            fieldLabel: 'PAN Number *',
            margin: "20 0 0 0",
            name: 'rb',
            id: 'radioPan',
            inputValue: '1',
            checked: true,
            listeners: {
                change: function (cb, nv, ov) {
                    if (nv) {
                        Ext.getCmp('AttachData').disable();
                        Ext.getCmp('PanData').enable();
                        Ext.select(".x-btn",Ext.getCmp('AttachData')).addCls('x-disabled x-btn-disabled x-item-disabled x-btn-default-small-disabled');
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'splitter'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            margin: "20 0 0 0",
            id: 'PanData',
            allowBlank: false,
            disabled: false
        }]
    },


    {
        xtype: 'container',
        html: '[ OR ]',
        margin: "10 0 0 175"
    },


    {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'radiofield',
            fieldLabel: 'Owner\'s Declaration *',
            margin: "10 0 0 0",
            name: 'rb',
            id: 'radioAttach',
            inputValue: '2',
            checked: false,
            listeners: {
                change: function (cb, nv, ov) {
                    if (nv) {
                        Ext.getCmp('PanData').disable();
                        Ext.getCmp('AttachData').enable();
                      Ext.select(".x-btn",Ext.getCmp('AttachData')).removeCls('x-disabled x-btn-disabled x-item-disabled x-btn-default-small-disabled');

                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'splitter'
        }, {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            id: 'AttachData',
            name: 'file_path',
            margin: "15 0 0 0",
            buttonText: 'Browse',
            disabled: true
        }]
    }] 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its working in online emulator. But In my application its not working. Is there is any alternate way.

Comment: Are you using the same id `AttachData` for your filefield?

Comment: I have checked.. actually the code is working fine in Chrome browser and not in IE 11

Comment: hi i resolved the problem with your help. thanks. I have changed the code in main ext-all-dev.js file " this['buttonEl-btnEl'].dom.disabled = false; " This resolve the enabling issue